# status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build android project getting this error

Could not GET 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\axum\\.android\\debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'thinkin'
            keyPassword 'thinkin'
            storeFile file('jks/thinkin')
            storePassword 'thinkin'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en","fr","ar"
        applicationId "com.thinkincab"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 14
        versionName "14"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        applicationIdSuffix '.app'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        resValue "string", "app_name", "Thinkin Cab"
        resValue "string", "google_key", google_map_keys
        buildConfigField "String", "google_map_keys", google_map_keys

        resValue "string", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", "962912134217064"
        resValue "string", "fb_login_protocol_scheme", "fb962912134217064"
        resValue "string", "ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN", "539f9500a16dda53d26461f5cb002188"
        resValue "string", "default_notification_channel_id", "fcm_default_channel"
        resValue "string", "google_signin_server_client_id", "57912751053-p7r9pk8g6vc1bki29l5vavquj7ogn1b3.apps.googleusercontent.com"

        //Demo credentials
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://phplaravel-720528-2396466.cloudwaysapps.com/"'
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_IMAGE_URL", '"http://phplaravel-720528-2396466.cloudwaysapps.com/storage/"'
        buildConfigField "String", "TERMS_CONDITIONS", '"https://cabpro.thinkindragon.com/privacy"'
        buildConfigField "String", "SITE_URL", '"http://phplaravel-720528-2396466.cloudwaysapps.com/"'

        buildConfigField "String", "DRIVER_PACKAGE", '"com.thinkincab.driver"'

        buildConfigField "String", "DEVICE_TYPE", '"android"'
        buildConfigField "String", "PAYPAL_CLIENT_TOKEN", '"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uRmluZ2VycHJpbnQiOiJlMWMzMGE4YmJlZmZlODk4MDJlMmY2ZGM5MzE4NjE1ZmJmZDQ4YWFjMTc3Y2ZkN2YxZjE4MDc1YjMzMzFkYmQ2fGNyZWF0ZWRfYXQ9MjAxOC0wOC0wN1QwNjo0MDoxMS4zNjI0Nzg4MzIrMDAwMFx1MDAyNm1lcmNoYW50X2lkPTM0OHBrOWNnZjNiZ3l3MmJcdTAwMjZwdWJsaWNfa2V5PTJuMjQ3ZHY4OWJxOXZtcHIiLCJjb25maWdVcmwiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zYW5kYm94LmJyYWludHJlZWdhdGV3YXkuY29tOjQ0My9tZXJjaGFudHMvMzQ4cGs5Y2dmM2JneXcyYi9jbGllbnRfYXBpL3YxL2NvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb24iLCJjaGFsbGVuZ2VzIjpbXSwiZW52aXJvbm1lbnQiOiJzYW5kYm94IiwiY2xpZW50QXBpVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuc2FuZGJveC5icmFpbnRyZWVnYXRld2F5LmNvbTo0NDMvbWVyY2hhbnRzLzM0OHBrOWNnZjNiZ3l3MmIvY2xpZW50X2FwaSIsImFzc2V0c1VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXNzZXRzLmJyYWludHJlZWdhdGV3YXkuY29tIiwiYXV0aFVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXV0aC52ZW5tby5zYW5kYm94LmJyYWludHJlZWdhdGV3YXkuY29tIiwiYW5hbHl0aWNzIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vb3JpZ2luLWFuYWx5dGljcy1zYW5kLnNhbmRib3guYnJhaW50cmVlLWFwaS5jb20vMzQ4cGs5Y2dmM2JneXcyYiJ9LCJ0aHJlZURTZWN1cmVFbmFibGVkIjp0cnVlLCJwYXlwYWxFbmFibGVkIjp0cnVlLCJwYXlwYWwiOnsiZGlzcGxheU5hbWUiOiJBY21lIFdpZGdldHMsIEx0ZC4gKFNhbmRib3gpIiwiY2xpZW50SWQiOm51bGwsInByaXZhY3lVcmwiOiJodHRwOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5jb20vcHAiLCJ1c2VyQWdyZWVtZW50VXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL3RvcyIsImJhc2VVcmwiOiJodHRwczovL2Fzc2V0cy5icmFpbnRyZWVnYXRld2F5LmNvbSIsImFzc2V0c1VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vY2hlY2tvdXQucGF5cGFsLmNvbSIsImRpcmVjdEJhc2VVcmwiOm51bGwsImFsbG93SHR0cCI6dHJ1ZSwiZW52aXJvbm1lbnROb05ldHdvcmsiOnRydWUsImVudmlyb25tZW50Ijoib2ZmbGluZSIsInVudmV0dGVkTWVyY2hhbnQiOmZhbHNlLCJicmFpbnRyZWVDbGllbnRJZCI6Im1hc3RlcmNsaWVudDMiLCJiaWxsaW5nQWdyZWVtZW50c0VuYWJsZWQiOnRydWUsIm1lcmNoYW50QWNjb3VudElkIjoiYWNtZXdpZGdldHNsdGRzYW5kYm94IiwiY3VycmVuY3lJc29Db2RlIjoiVVNEIn0sIm1lcmNoYW50SWQiOiIzNDhwazljZ2YzYmd5dzJiIiwidmVubW8iOiJvZmYifQ=="'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.applicationId}_V${variant.versionCode}_VN-${variant.versionName}_" + new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd') + ".apk"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //      Fire Base
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    //      Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.37.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    //      Rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    //      Networking (Retrofit)
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
    //      DI (Butter knife)
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    //      Image processing (Glide, Lottie, circular image & Image picker)
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.4'
    //      Others
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
    implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.2'
    /*      dimen       */
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    //      Car Animation in Rate card
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    // comment below line & its relative code in files, if you face issue while generate signed apk.
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1'
    //      payment gateway...
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.0.0'
    /*      toasty      */
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    // Page Indicator using Recycler view
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.13'
    implementation 'com.ryanjeffreybrooks:indefinitepagerindicator:1.0.9'
    //    implementation project(':payumoneypayment')
    implementation "com.github.YarikSOffice:lingver:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'


    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


}
```

Comment: Can you please post your project level `build.gradle`? Because it is most likely that you're using `bintray` in the repositories block. Which is now shut down.

Comment: fixed by removing bintray instances added mavencentral